# Hamburger Menu not working on reduced browser size

Tags: menus, browser-compatibility

I'm currently working on my site but having a small issue with the hamburger menu. It works fine on an actual mobile device, but when I reduce the browser size so that the hamburger appears, nothing happens when I click on it. It does not show my menu. The only thing that happens is a '#' symbol appearing at the end of my URL when I click on it.

Any idea on whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

Without any available code it's a bit difficult to figure out what's going on for sure; however, I'm guessing the problem is that there is some JavaScript code that activates the hamburger menu only if a screen is below a certain width. 
The script only runs when the page first loads, so it is only then that the screen width is checked - in your mobile device the initial width is small enough, so the code runs, in your screen the initial width is greater than set by the code, so it doesn't run.
The solution would be to simply locate the code snippet (in many themes it is inside a file called `navigation.js`) and remove the part that checks the width, so the code runs regardless of the screen size.